# Invalid Operation Exception In Calling Async Method from inside a Parallel.ForEach Loop

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-services

I have inherited a windows service that processes a large number of e-mails in a queue. Sounds simple, Grab queue, send e-mail, if SmtpClient.SendAsync does not return an error from the call back then flag the e-mail in the DB as being sent.. I am using a Semaphore to waitone on the thread so multiple calls can be made to the Async Send method of the SMTP Client. This is the only way I can get the status and per Microsoft docs it has to finish the operation before another call can be made async. So now for the fun part. I decided to use a Parallel.ForEach to get he queue like so. This method is called in the Windows Service OnStart. Please note I have tried calling this method on a separate Thread and get the same results.

I am thinking that either A, I am missing something obvious, due to my lack of knowledge on threading, or something is flat bugged. Most likely A.

```
 private static void ProcessEmailQueue()
    {
        List<EmailQueue> emailQueue =
            _repository.Select<EmailQueue>().Where(x => x.EmailStatuses.EmailStatus == "Pending").ToList();
        Parallel.ForEach(emailQueue, message =>
                                         {
                                             _smtpMail.FromAddress = message.FromAddress;
                                             _smtpMail.ToAddress = message.ToAddress;
                                             _smtpMail.Subject = message.Subject;
                                             _smtpMail.SendAsHtml = message.IsHtml > 0;
                                             _smtpMail.MessageBody = message.MessageBody;
                                             _smtpMail.UserToken = message.EmailQueueID;
                                             bool sendStatus = _smtpMail.SendMessage();
                                                 // THIS BLOWS UP with InvalidOperation Exception
                                         });
    }
```

Here is the SMTP Method being called from withing the loop.

```
public bool SendMessage()
    {
        mailSendSemaphore = new Semaphore(0, 10); // This is defined as  private static Semaphore mailSendSemaphore;
        try
        {
            var fromAddress = new MailAddress(FromAddress);
            var toAddress = new MailAddress(ToAddress);

            using (var mailMessage = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress))
            {
                mailMessage.Subject = Subject;
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = SendAsHtml;
                mailMessage.Body = MessageBody;
                Envelope = mailMessage;
                smtp.SendCompleted += smtp_SendCompleted;
                smtp.SendAsync(mailMessage, UserToken);
                mailSendSemaphore.WaitOne();
                return _mailSent;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Error(exception);

            return _mailSent;
        }
    }
```

CALLBACK For Smtp Send

```
 private void smtp_SendCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
        }
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            _mailSent = true;
        }
        mailSendSemaphore.Release(2);
    }
```

Here is the Exception, took a few  to get it for some odd reason.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
```

Message=An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendAsync(MailMessage message, Object userToken)
       at DFW.Infrastructure.Communications.SmtpMail.SendMessage() in SmtpMail.cs:line 71
       at EmaiProcessorService.EmailQueueService.b_*0(EmailQueue message) in Service1.cs:line 57
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c*_DisplayClass2d`2.<ForEachWorker>b__23(Int32 i)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__c()
  InnerException:

Seems my waitone is getting obliterated by System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel

Comment: As ever, please give the *details* of the InvalidOperationException - which line is throwing an exception, what's the message, etc?

Comment: Trying to catch it as we speak, it seems to be somewhat buried as I can't seem to get it in any of my try catch blocks

Comment: Debugging Windows Services Is not very entertaining :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on why you're using a Semaphore here, but you're almost certainly using it incorrectly. You're creating a new semaphore instance for each call to `SendMessage`. Also, you're calling `WaitOne` on it once, and then calling `Release(2)`, so eventually you'll have more releases than acquires. That's probably what causes your `InvalidOperationException`.

It doesn't do you any good to parallelize processing of the email queue, since you can only send one message at a time. And trying to do it asynchronously inside of the `Parallel.Foreach` is just more needless complication.

You're better off using something like `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, and having a simple loop that sends one message at a time.

```
List<EmailQueue> emailQueue =
    _repository.Select<EmailQueue>().Where(x => x.EmailStatuses.EmailStatus == "Pending").ToList();

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessEmailQueue, emailQueue);

void ProcessEmailQueue(object state)
{
    List<EmailQueue> emailQueue = (List<EmailQueue>)state;
    foreach (var message in EmailQueue)
    {
        // Format and send message here.
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can do the same thing with a `Task`. The point is that you just need a single thread to process the queue sequentially. Since you can't send more than one message at a time, `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't do you any good.

EDIT:

If you need to do multiple sends at a time, you can probably modify your original code. First, initialize the semaphore at class scope:

```
private static Semaphore mailSendSemaphore = new Semaphore(10, 10);
```

Then, in your `SendMessage` method:

```
bool SendMessage()
{
    // acquire semaphore. This will block until there's a slot available.
    mailSendSemaphore.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        // do all your processing here, including sending the message.
        // use Send rather than SendAsync
    }
    finally
    {
        mailSendSemaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

There's no need to use `SendAsync`.

Comment: Let me try some of your recommendations

Comment: Ok so that runs and doesn't blow up however I am not able to get the bool return value.. "Status" when using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessEmailQueue, emailQueue);

Comment: If it's a Windows Forms application, you could use `BackgroundWorker` and fire the Progress event for every mail sent. If you use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, you can have it call a defined callback with the status.

Comment: Thanks much for both responses.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, now that we've got the error text, it seems fairly clear:

> Message=An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method.

This concurs with the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx):

Two simple options:

- Create a fixed number of clients, and a queue of messages to send. Make each client take a message from the queue each time it finishes, until the queue is empty. [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) is good for this.
- Create a new [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4971yhhc.aspx) per message. This could cause you to effectively launch a DOS attack on your SMTP server, which isn't ideal.

To be honest, it's not really clear why you're using `SendAsync` when you're then just waiting for the message to be sent anyway...

Comment: Async was the only way to get any type of response to return back to the service. I have to mark if the message has been sent.